# Dynamic two dimensional array creation in boost shared memory

Tags: boost, shared-memory

I would like to store a 2 dimensional array in shared memory using boost.
I do not know the size of this array at compile time, only at run time.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Some code would be soooo appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `multi_array` with a `boost::interprocess::allocator`. This would requires that `multi_array` supports stateful allocators.

If not, you can allocate your memory manually in any way you want, and use [`multi_array_ref`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_ref):

> multi_array_ref is a multi-dimensional container adaptor. It provides the MultiArray interface over any contiguous block of elements. multi_array_ref exports the same interface as multi_array, with the exception of the constructors.

### Trying `multi_array`

Using `multi_array` blows up because it doesn't support rich pointers (`offset_ptr<double>` instead of `double*`) internally. [See Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cTazGK)

So, using `multi_array_ref` would be in order:

### Demo `multi_array_ref`

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zcrTev)**

```
#ifdef NO_SHM_ONLINE
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#endif
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
// debug, demo output:
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <random>

static std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{}() };
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bma = boost::multi_array_types;

namespace {
    #ifdef NO_SHM_ONLINE
        using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
    #else
        using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    #endif

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;

    template <typename T>
    using Vector = boost::container::vector<T, Alloc<T> >;
}

int main() {
    Segment seg(bip::open_or_create, "my_shared_mem", 1024);
    
    auto rows = 1 + prng()%5;
    auto cols = 1 + prng()%7;

    auto& backing = *seg.find_or_construct<Vector<double> >("my_backing")
                        (rows*cols, seg.get_segment_manager());

    // ensure enough backing storage
    backing.resize(rows*cols); // previous runs might have required less
    backing.shrink_to_fit();   // optional: might not be optimal

    boost::multi_array_ref<double, 2> data(
            backing.data(),
            boost::extents[rows][cols]);

    fmt::print("shape: {} num_elements(): {} free in segment: {}\n",
            std::vector(data.shape(), data.shape()+2),
            data.num_elements(),
            seg.get_free_memory()
        );

    std::iota(data.origin(), data.origin() + data.num_elements(), 1);

    fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(data, "\n"));
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
shape: {3, 5} num_elements(): 15 free in segment: 576
{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}
{6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0}
{11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0}
```

Or indeed, on subsequent runs:

[image]

### Alternatively, Nested Vectors

This risks more fragmentation, and indexing isn't nearly as powerful as with Boost Multi Array, and **much** more error-prone due the responsibility to keep the dimension invariants.

YMMV, just for completeness:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YvjPhz)**

```
#ifdef NO_SHM_ONLINE
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#endif
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
// debug, demo output:
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <random>

static std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{}() };
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bma = boost::multi_array_types;

namespace {
    #ifdef NO_SHM_ONLINE
        using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
    #else
        using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    #endif

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;

    template <typename T>
    using Vector = boost::container::vector<T, Alloc<T> >;

    template <typename T>
    using Matrix = Vector<Vector<T> >;
}

int main() {
    Segment seg(bip::open_or_create, "my_shared_mem", 1024);
    
    auto rows = 1 + prng()%5;
    auto cols = 1 + prng()%7;

    auto& nested = *seg.find_or_construct<Matrix<double> >("manual_nested_vectors")
                        (seg.get_segment_manager());

    // ensure enough nested storage
    nested.clear();
    nested.shrink_to_fit();
    nested.assign(rows, Vector<double>(cols, seg.get_segment_manager())); // not very efficient

    fmt::print("shape: {}x{} total elements: {} free in segment: {}\n",
            rows, cols,
            rows*cols,
            seg.get_free_memory()
        );

    size_t base = 1;
    for(auto& row : nested) {
        std::iota(row.begin(), row.end(), base);
        base += cols;
    }

    fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(nested, "\n"));
}
```

Again, interactively (compare the allocation footprints; also, note the order in which `clear()` and `shrink_to_fit()` are issued matters greatly):

[image]

Comment: Added live demos for [`multi_array_ref`](https://godbolt.org/z/zcrTev) (recommended) and [nested vectors](https://godbolt.org/z/YvjPhz)